# Start activity from RecyclerView (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have Xamarin app with RecyclerView.

I have TextView in block. I want to start activity on click.

Here is code:

```
public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    var movieViewHolder = (MovieViewHolder)holder;
    movieViewHolder.MovieNameTextView.Text = movies[position].CompanyName;
    var position_new = position + 1;
    movieViewHolder.MovieCount.Text = position_new.ToString();

    movieViewHolder.MovieNameTextView.Click += delegate {
        StartActivity(typeof(ClientLogin));
    };
}
```

But I have this error:

> The name 'StartActivity' does not exist in the current context.
>   Cannot resolve symbol 'StartActivity'

[image]

How I can start activity from Recycler view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
movieViewHolder.MovieNameTextView.Context.StartActivity(typeof(ClientLogin));
```

Comment: Specified cast is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes and you should. StartActivity is a function available in the Context class, not the adapter. So grab a instance of context (maybe from the ViewHolders itemView) and call `holder.ItemView.Context.StartActivity(typeof(ClientLogin));`.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass in an instance of the Activity (Context) in the MoviesAdapter constructor. Save this instance in a private field and use it later when navigating to the new Activity on the click event.

```
Activity _context;

public MovieAdapter(Activity context)
{
    _context = context;
}
```

When you create the object of the Adapter you pass in the instance of the Activity:

```
var movieAdapter = MovieAdapter(this);
```

Then modify your click delegate to

```
movieViewHolder.MovieNameTextView.Click += delegate
{
    _context.StartActivity(typeof(ClientLogin));
};
```